# GETDATE() insert with spaces SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have three tables in database. I have the column `Operation_Date` in all of them. I set the column default value to (`GETDATE()`), and its data type is `VARCHAR(50)` and I don't have any coding in my C# Windows application that inserts value to `Operation_Date`.

Issue: When I insert rows to tables the operation_Date separates month, day and year with space like this (MAY  2 2020). I get two spaces after month and one space after days.

I tried to make a query on SQL Server to insert and the same problem occurs. I tried changing data type to datetime but with not success.

Note: this issue occurs only in two tables. And I am pretty sure the three tables have the same settings.

Is there anyway to force a certain date format for the default value in SQL Server? And what could make this issue happen?

This is the query I used:

```
USE [EasyManagementSystem]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Attendance] ([Employee_No], [Present], [Leave], [Othe_Leave], [Month], [Year])
VALUES ('l-8068', 30, 0, 0, 'MAY', 2020)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh?  Why would you be storing a date as a string.  That is just wrong.  There is a perfectly good data type for dates, called `date`.

If you want this to be set on input, then just give it a default value.  Your table creation should look like:

```
create attendance (
    . . .
    operation_date date default getdate()
);
```

Voila!  It will just work.  If you want the month or year, you can use the `month()` and `year()` functions.

Comment: Thank you sir. Having Datatype as date is annoying when it inserts time, too. I get it like this : 2020-05-02 19:10:15.550. it makes it hard when trying to retrieve data my date

Comment: I just re-created the tables using your suggested query and it worked.